# Failed to add Google Assistant Action to Botium, Botium Box, botium-cli

Tags: node.js, testing, chatbot, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to connect a Google Assistant Action to Botium Box or botium-cli. 
I followed all the steps in the Botium Connector for Google Assistant explanation.

When I try to add the generated botium.json to Botium Box I get the following error message.

```
Chatbot connection failed - Loading Botium plugin failed
```

When I try to start the emulator in botium-cli I get this error

```
Error: Loading Botium plugin failed
at Validate.Validate.then (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\botium-core\src\containers\PluginConnectorContainer.js:59:15)
```

The botium.json looks like this

```json
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "Botium Project Google Assistant",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "google-assistant",
      "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_CLIENT_ID": "xxx",
      "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_CLIENT_SECRET": "xxx",
      "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_REFRESH_TOKEN": "xxx",
      "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_TYPE": "authorized_user",
      "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_START_UTTERANCE": "talk to xxx",
      "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_END_UTTERANCE": "Cancel"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that Botium cannot load the google assistant connector module.

The google assistant connector is part of Botium Box since version 1.1, see the [release notes](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-box-release-notes-66cf337bc1a1). It is part of Botium CLI 0.0.46.

Please verify that you installed those versions at minimum. If the versions are fine, then please run botium-cli in verbose mode (--verbose) and attach the log output.

Comment: I am running Botium Box Version 1.3.0 and Botium CLI 0.0.43

https://pastebin.com/QfUWAKwa

Comment: The log file you posted shows a failure I don't understand myself. I notified the developer of the google-assistant-connector to find out what's wrong here. Will follow up here.

Comment: Hi did you hear anything back yet?

Comment: The bug is in our backlog and will be solved this or next week.

Comment: We were not able to reproduce it in our development environments. Can you please post your package-lock.json, so we can compare the package versions of the dependencies, please ?

Comment: Thanks. We found the solution, connector was not prepared for a version upgrade of an indirect dependency. Update will be available in the next days.

Comment: Dose the Google Assistant connector support regular expressions?

Comment: Using regular expressions for assertions is supported by all Botium connectors (https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/Botium-Configuration#scripting_matching_mode)